# Where to put Using block when open Process?

Tags: c#

I have process that i am opening and create file on dist and subscribe to this procees `ProcessExitedEvent`:

```
public int InvokeProcess(WiresharkProcesses process, string args)
{
    try
    {
        string processToInvoke = null;
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Process pros = new Process();
        startInfo .FileName = processToInvoke;
        startInfo .RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo .RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo .RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo .UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo .CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo .Arguments = args;
        pros.StartInfo = startInfo ;
        pros.ErrorDataReceived += pros_ErrorDataReceived;
        pros.OutputDataReceived += pros_OutputDataReceived;
        pros.Exited += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (ProcessExitedEvent != null)
                ProcessExitedEvent(pros.Id);
        };
        pros.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        pros.Start();
        pros.BeginOutputReadLine();
        pros.BeginErrorReadLine();

        return pros.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

private void ProcessExitedEvent(int processId)
{
   // Copy file
   // Delete file
}
```

This process create file on disk and after `ProcessExitedEvent` event fired i want to copy this file to another location and than delete the old file, but although the event fired after the process exit the my code failed to delete the old file because the file is still in use so i want to ensure that my process die by using `using block` 
so where i need to put this block ?

Comment: Is the ProcessExitedEvent firing correctly after the proccess ends?

Comment: I just tried a test case of launching a process, editing a file in that process, and then deleting that file in the Process.Exited event in the calling process.  It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I very much doubt that a `using` statement will help here. `Process.Dispose` doesn't kill the other process - it just releases the CLR handle to the other process. (To be honest, I don't remember every seeing anyone use a `using` statement for `Process` - unlike most disposable resources, I wouldn't worry about this one.)

I'm surprised you can't delete the file, but it may be that the OS is just flushing buffers or something as the process dies. You might want to try waiting a second before deleting the file... although that *shouldn't* really be necessary. Are you sure it's not something like a virus checker that is picking up the file?

Comment: If i am using Thread.Sleep(2000) its working fine but it freeze all my UI so i wonder if i can use another solution

Comment: @user2214609: Well don't do it in the UI thread - or start a timer to fire in 2 seconds. Or if you're using C# 5, you could use `await Task.Delay(2000);`. There are lots of ways of adding a delay without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: I am using .Net 4, something for .Net 4 maybe ?

Comment: @user2214609: A timer or a different thread would be fine. Or use async/await with http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Comment: after the ProcessExit event fired up i can fired an event to my main form and for example start timer for 3 seconds and after the timer will finish try to delete the file ? is it good solution ?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I am with you; I don't ever recall seeing a `using` being used with a `Process`.  +1.

Comment: @user2214609: Yes, that's what I was suggesting, basically.

Comment: But after my event will fired up to my main form this will be in same thread or i need to wait by using ManualResetEvent for 3 seconds ?

Comment: @user2214609: I'm afraid I didn't understand your comment at all, but you shouldn't need to be in the UI thread to delete a file, and I wouldn't use ManualResetEvent here. Whether the timer fires in the UI thread or not depends on which timer class you use and how you use it.

Comment: My ProcessExit event fired up from my class, is it batter to start the timer from this class or from my form class ?

Comment: @user2214609: I'd just do it in the handler - there's no reason to assume that *all* handlers will want to get the event delayed.

Comment: What do you mean in the handler (i am a new developer...) ?

Comment: @user2214609: In the method you're using to handle the event (your form). To be honest, if you're really, really new to C# I would back away from complicated things (such as threads and timers) and learn the core aspects of the language first - it's likely to help you in the long run. (For example, your form is also a class, so talk about "form" vs "class" isn't particularly helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

I would move the file instead of copying and deleting it. Is there a reason why you need to copy the file and then delete the original? Why don't you move the file instead? If it's being moved to the same physical hard drive, usually moving it is far less costly than copying and deleting it, and if it isn't, you can still at least save on file operations.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion use this may be it solve your problem rather then firing an event. Something happens to me and i solve it by using `WaitForExit()`.

```
var process = Process.Start(...);
process.WaitForExit();

// Delete your file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if this solves the problem:

```
    public void InvokeProcess(WiresharkProcesses process, string args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string processToInvoke = null;
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            using (Process pros = new Process())
            {
                startInfo.FileName = processToInvoke;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.Arguments = args;
                pros.StartInfo = startInfo;

                //pros.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                pros.Start();
                pros.WaitForExit();
            }
            // Copy file
            // Delete file
        });
    }
```

Comment: When I read his code, I assumed he wanted some form of simultaneous multiprocessing. Your modification kind of kills that...

Comment: Thank you. I added a Task.Factory.StartNew